# Sticky Bootstrap Sidebar creates gap along right margin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I add `position:fixed` to my bootstrap sidebar, it leaves a gap on the right side.  I have tried removing margins, padding, etc but have had no luck.

Here's what the gap looks like:
[image: the active element with the right arrow is supposed to extend to the full width of the parent.]

Without `position:fixed`, the active element in the sidebar extends to the full width of the parent.

html:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 matchHeight" id="side-menu" style="margin-left:30px;">
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar" id="timeline_sidemenu" style="list-style-type:none;">
            <li style="text-align:center;color:#999999; margin-bottom:20px;border:0px;"><img src="//i.imgur.com/zOeEoKE.png" width="50"/><br />Instagram</li>
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#"><img src="{{url_for('static', filename='images/icons/timeline_hover.png')}}" width="18" style="margin-top:-5px;" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Timeline</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/product-evolution/" class="swap" ><img src="{{url_for('static', filename='images/icons/product.png')}}" data-image-regular="{{url_for('static', filename='images/icons/product.png')}}" data-image-hover="{{url_for('static', filename='images/icons/product_hover.png')}}" width='18'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Product Evolution</a></li>
            <li><a href="/insta_charts/" class="swap"><img src="{{url_for('static', filename='images/icons/chart.png')}}" data-image-regular="{{url_for('static', filename='images/icons/chart.png')}}" data-image-hover="{{url_for('static', filename='images/icons/chart_hover.png')}}" width='18' style="margin-top:-5px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Growth Data/Charts</a></li>
            <li><a href="/90-days/" class="swap"><img src="{{url_for('static', filename='images/icons/flag.png')}}" data-image-regular="{{url_for('static', filename='images/icons/flag.png')}}" data-image-hover="{{url_for('static', filename='images/icons/flag_hover.png')}}" width='18' style="margin-top:-5px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;First 90 days in Market</a></li>
            <li><a href="/public-discussion/" class="swap"><img src="{{url_for('static', filename='images/icons/publicdiscussion.png')}}" data-image-regular="{{url_for('static', filename='images/icons/publicdiscussion.png')}}" data-image-hover="{{url_for('static', filename='images/icons/publicdiscussion_hover.png')}}" width="18"  style="margin-top:-5px;" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Public Discussion</a></li>
            <li style="border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;"><a href="/founder-activity/" class="swap"><img src="{{url_for('static', filename='images/icons/avatar.png')}}" data-image-regular="{{url_for('static', filename='images/icons/avatar.png')}}" data-image-hover="{{url_for('static', filename='images/icons/avatar_hover.png')}}" width="18"  style="margin-top:-3px;" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Founder Activity</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

css:

```
#side-menu{
  background-color:#efefef;
  border-left:1px solid #cccccc;
  border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;
  border-right:1px solid #cccccc;
  border-top:1px solid #cccccc;
  padding:25px 0px 0px 0px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #cccccc;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  position:relative;
}
#timeline_sidemenu{
  position:fixed;
}
.nav-sidebar > li{
  border-top:1px solid #cccccc;
}
/* Sidebar navigation */
.nav-sidebar > li > a {
  font-family:  proxima-nova,Proxima Nova,helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.nav-sidebar > li > a:hover,
.nav-sidebar > li > a:focus {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}
.nav-sidebar  a{
  color:#999999;
}

.nav-sidebar  a:hover,
.nav-sidebar  a:focus {
  color: #666666;
  background-color: #171919;
}
.nav-sidebar > .active > a,
.nav-sidebar > .active > a:hover,
.nav-sidebar > .active > a:focus {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family:  proxima-nova,Proxima Nova,helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #666666;
}
.nav-sidebar > .active > a::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  top:10px; /* controls vertical position */
  bottom:auto;
  right:0px;
  border-width:10px 12px 10px 0;
  border-color:transparent #cccccc;
}
.nav-sidebar > .active > a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  top:10px; /* controls vertical position */
  bottom:auto;
  right:-1px;
  border-width:10px 10px 10px 0;
  border-color:transparent #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit upset I wasn't able to get it working with pure css, but I was able to semi-resolve this issue with a jQuery library by the name of [Sticky-kit](http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/#reference).

I ended up removing `position:fixed` property from css and just included `$("#timeline_sidemenu").stick_in_parent();` in between script tags of html code.

Comment: Can you provide a working link as codes are not working as designed in image at jsfiddle. Did you try position:fixed at #side-menu